# Swagger undertow

Tags: swagger, undertow

Ahoj,

I'm looking for example of integrating swagger into undertow based application.
I've got undertow configured like this:

```
        HttpHandler routes = new RoutingHandler()
            .post("/v1/create", endpoint::create)
            .get("health", healthEndpoint::handleRequest)
            .setFallbackHandler(ResponseCodeHandler.HANDLE_404);

    Undertow server = Undertow
            .builder()
            .addHttpListener(8080, hostAddress)
            .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
            .setHandler(new AsyncHttpHandler(routes))
            .build();
    return server;
```

And then in endpoint I've got plain method with HttpServerExchange as argument,

Is there possibility to integrate swagger into such app, based on annotations not json spec. 
In result I'd like to host on server(inside app) side swagger-ui page,

I don't have spring in application,

Thanks,

Comment: I'm looking for the solution of same problem as well.